# crop MODIS raster files in HDF: extents do not overlap R

Tags: r

I want to reproject my downloaded MODIS files. But i get this error 'Error: [crop] extents do not overlap'. Not quite sure what the problem is with my script. I have downloaded the MODIS data for West Africa. See my projection script if I need to do something else. Thanks for your assistance in advance.

```
ext = ext(-6, 14, -8, 14.5)
aoi = ext

 rlist = sapply(files_loop, FUN = function(x){rast(x)[[1]]}) 
  rsrc = sprc(rlist) 
  rm(rlist)
  m = mosaic(rsrc) 
  #m[m<1]=NA 
  #m[m>=1]=1 
  #land_cover = rast("filename")
  #m <- rast()
  r <- ifelse(m<1, NA, 1)
  m <- project(r,"epsg:4326")
  mc <- crop(m,land_cover)
  #m = project(m,"epsg:4326")
  #m=crop(m,land_cover)
  writeRaster(m, paste("D:/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx_",dates[i], list_years_month[i], ".tif", sep = ""),overwrite = T)
  rm(m, rsrc) #remove temporary files
  gc()
  tmpFiles(remove = T)
  print(i)


 new code error [show (m)][1]
[show(landcover][2]
[code error][3]
[ext][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhSfP.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A54La.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tY9z.jpg
```

Comment: Can you please improve the question by removing everything (including the loop) that is not directly related to the problem you describe? All you should show is the call to `crop` and `show()` the input to that call, and the error message where it occurs.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I have remove the loop. It was actually that section only that gives me the extent error.

Comment: I edited your question to show where the error happens (if I understand you well). Can you run this code, and see if that is true, and then include the error message where it happens? And can you also include the results from `show(land_cover)`, `show(r)`, and `show(m)`?

Comment: Dear Rob, thanks for your comments on my script. I have run your code and the error is that "argument to "which" is not logical. Maybe i didn't place this well in my original code? I have just added your code and commented my old lines where i think you have rewritten. So after running show(m), i think the problem might have been with the long, lat. Because what i entered to download the files is not what i have seen in the show(m) result. Any reason why this has changed. I have edited the main question and added these error messages and my desired area of interest so it is a bit clear.